# Improving Time Bound of this Algorithm past $O(n^2)$

Tags: algorithms, subsequences

I recently came across the following interesting problem - one is given a sequence of `X`s and `Y`s such as `XXYXYXYYXYXXXYX`, and consider a sequence to be good if, as you start at the left and move right, the number of `X`s is greater than or equal to the number of `Y`s at any point except at the very end, at which the two quantities must be equal.

One must determine the number of points at which changing either a single `X` to `Y` or a single `Y` to `X` in a given sequence will yield a good sequence.

I initially considered traveling through the sequence linearly and checking if toggling the letter at that point would yield a good sequence, however that approach is on the order of $O(n\cdot n)=O(n^2)$ in the worst case where n is the length of the sequence. However, I was wondering if there was some faster method to do it.

EDIT: I made the observation that for any sequence, if the number of possible changes is greater than 0, than only one type of change will work (either changing an `X` to `Y` or `Y` to `X`) given the condition at the end that the number of `X` and `Y` must be equal.

Comment: More appropriate for cs.stackexchange.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a hint. Suppose the sequence contains $n-1$ Xs and $n+1$ Ys, so that you need to change some Y to X. You can compute for each position $k \in [1,\ldots,2n]$ the number of Xs minus the number of Ys; let's call that a "report". Changing a Y to an X affects the report in a certain, easy to describe, way. On the other hand, whether a sequence is good corresponds to a very simple property of the report.

Putting everything together, you should get an $O(n)$ algorithm.